# ssl connection, using a hostname that is not in the SAN list of the host's certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate, hostname

I am quite new to ssl stuffs but I am afraid I can guess the final answer of the following problem/question:

We are building hardware (let's call them servers) that WILL have IP address modifications along there lifetime. Each Server must be reachable in a secured manner. We are planning to use a TLS 1.3 secured connection to perform some actions on the servers (update firmware, change configuration and so on). As a consequence we need to provide the server's with one certificate (each) so that they can state their identity. PKI issue is out of the scope of this question (we suppose) and we can take for granted that the clients and the servers will share a common trusted CA to ensure the SSL handshake goes ok. The server's will serve http connection on there configured (changeable) IP addresses only. There is no DNS involved on the loop.

We are wondering how to set the servers' certificates appropriately.

As IP will change, it cannot be used as the common name in the server's certificate.

Therefore, we are considering using something more persistent such as a serial number or a MAC address.

The problem is, as there is no DNS in the loop, the client can not issue http request to [www.serialNumberOfServer.com](http://www.serialNumberOfServer.com) and must connect to http://x.y.z.t (which will change frequently (at least frequently enough so that we don't issue a new server's certificate at each time))

If we get it right, ssl handshake requires to have the hostname (that's in the URL we are connecting to) matching either the commonName of the server's Certificate or one of its Subject's Alternative Name (SAN). Right? Here, it would be x.y.z.t.
So we think we are stucked in a situation in which the server cannot use it's IP to prove its identity and the client wants to use it exclusively to connect to the server.

Is there any work around?

Are we missing something?
Any help would be very (VERY) appreciated. Do not hesitated in cas you should need more detailed explanation!

For what it's worth, the development environment will be Qt using the QNetworkAccessManager/QSSlstuffs framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not having the client use DNS at all, then you do have a problem.  The *right* solution is to use DNS or static hostname lists (/etc/hosts, eg, on unix* or hosts.txt on windows eg.).  That will let you set names appropriately.

If you can only use IP addresses, another option is to put all of your IP addresses into the certificate that the server might use.  This is only doable if you have a reasonable small number of addresses that they might get assigned to.

Or you could keep a cache of certificates on the server with one address for each, and have part of the webserver start process to select the right certificate.  Requires a bit more complex startup.

**Edit:** Finally, some SSL stacks (e.g. openssl) let you decide whether or not each particular verification error should be accepted as an error or that it can be ignored.  This would let you override the errors on the client side.  However, this is hard to implement properly and very prone to security issues if you don't bind the remote certificate properly it means you're subjecting yourself to man-in-the-middle or other attacks by blindly accepting any old certificate.  I don't remember if Qt's SSL library gives you this level of flexibility or not (I don't believe so but didn't go pull up the documentation).

Comment: That's what I suspected.
Isn't there a way on the client side to connect to an IP and tell the client it's ok if the certificate  has a declared common name that might/will be different?

Comment: Yes, let me add one more note above.  But I doubt you'll like it.

Comment: Well, That's what I was afraid of.
We will try to experiment with the /etc/hosts solution crossing every fingers we have it works as expected. The side effect is that our client will have to connect everywhen to www.serialNumberOfServer.com  and the mapping with the IP adress will be hold by the /etc/hosts file.
This is a slighly different design on the client side than the one we elaborated first.
as long as the ssl layer tries to match serialNumberOfServer.com with the server's CN/SAN (and not the IP  associated whitin /etc/hosts), it should work.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and advice @wes

Answer (score 0):

Went back on the subject 9 mont later!
Turns out there is an easy solution (at least with Qt framework)

Qt's QNetworkRequest::setPeerVerifyName does the job for us. It allows to connect to an host using its IP and verify a given CN during SSL handshake

See Qt's documentation extract below:

```
void QNetworkRequest::setPeerVerifyName(const QString &peerName)
Sets peerName as host name for the certificate validation, instead of the one used for the TCP connection.
This function was introduced in Qt 5.13.
See also peerVerifyName.
```

Just tested it positively right now